# mat-sidenav-content content is being overflowed behind the pages scrollbar

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-bootstrap

I am running Angular 7 with Bootstrap and I am trying to setup `mat-sidenav-container`

The issue I am facing is all the content inside `mat-sidenav-content` (which is the main content for the page) is overflowing behind the browsers scrollbar for the content.

I have messed around with changing the overflow on this to no avail. I know adding a margin will probably fix it but I feel that it's messy cause some pages don't have a scroll bar.

Is this something to do with bootstrap being used as I am using this example
https://stackblitz.com/angular/klqaabgjllb?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.ts

[image: content overflowing behind scrollbar]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add an `autosize` attribute to your `mat-sidenav-container`. It helps with recomputing margins & stuff with Angular material drawers.

It has a cost in terms of performance though, so you might want to put a timer to disable it a few seconds after the animation is done if it's important for you.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was

```
// component.html
<mat-sidenav-container #sidenavContainer>
      <mat-sidenav opened mode="side" #sidenav fixedInViewport="true">
        Side Nav
      </mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content>
        Main Content
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>


// component.ts
export class Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("sidenavContainer", { static: false })
  sideNavContainer: MatSidenavContainer;

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // calling updateContentMargins on next tick, fixes the spacing.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.sideNavContainer.updateContentMargins();
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `position: absolute;` from the css of the page container outside of the `mat-sidenav` fixed this one for me and pushed the scrollbar outside of it.